# Audio Peak Meter

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers, audio, simulation-nodes

I’m trying to make an accurate audio peak meter in blender and can’t seem to get it right. So here’s what I want to do… The Z scale of object B is being animated by an audio file which I imported in the graph editor. So it is variating between 0 and 1. I want object A to move along the z axis at the peak level (at the top of object B). But I want it to stay at the max value for 3 seconds even if object B goes below. And after 3 seconds I want it to change to the current peak level. And repeat.

In other words I want to store the maximum of a dynamic value for 3 seconds and then change to the current value. I want this happening constantly.

I’ve tried to do this in multiple ways but can’t seem to get it. I saw a video on how it was possible with animation nodes. Here is the link for that : https://youtu.be/mjYf-tD2SqM

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use simulation nodes or something similar (or do a geometry based loop), because you need to get information from a previous state.

There could be a workaround in your case, since you are only checking back 3 seconds. What you can do is to duplicate the driver 3 times and (so you have 3 copies) and offset each by 1 sec forwards (so fist is regular, second is ahead by 1 sec and the third is ahead by 2 sec), then you check if any of them reached the max volume and if any of them are, you set the z to be the max.